# How to make funnels on `screen_view` Firebase event

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

For an iOS app with 3 screens (A, B and C), I would like to create a funnel to see users's that have visited screen A then B then C (Just like I can in Google Analytics).

Firebase (out-of-the-box) tracks all screens using the `screen_view` event. However whilst creating a funnel I am not able to select the `screen_name` param which is being sent along with the `screen_view` event.

How could I achieve such a funnel creation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, Firebase unfortunately does not support closed funnels. That means you can't see the subset of events of the previous event.

> Funnels in Firebase are open funnels, meaning that users do not have to complete a previous step (e.g., Step 1) in order to be included in the metrics for a subsequent step (e.g., Step 2). [1](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317523?hl=en)

To your question about filtering on event parameters. That is not possible either. If you want to create a custom dashboard you can export your events to BigQuery and then query your events there. Another option would be to create compound events from your `screen_views`, e.g. `A_then_B` when a user navigates from screen *A* to screen *B*.

Comment: So strange that Google is promoting Firebase so badly while it lacks a lot of the features that GoogleAnalytics has

Comment: use bigquery. firebase dashboard meets very few requirements right now.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena Would you be able to recommend some tools to use BigQuery effectively for this? Is it Tableau or something else altogether?

Comment: @kidoman not sure what you mean by effectively. If its visualisations you want then you can visualise the data on google data studio which is already linked with BigQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can now enable Google Analytics for Firebase (in the console). This will enable automatic transfer of all of the Firebase Analytics events (including screen_view) to Google Analytics. Google Analytics in turn allows to build funnels for events and parameter values. A funnel in GA can be closed or open.